# bug with mouse release event for brush in d3 graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, brush

I am trying to use 
[d3.js Multiple Area Chart](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/MultipleAreaChartsD3/) for representing a collection of data. The graph building part was completed successfully. I've created a brush for timeline dragging and the bug is that, I guess, the mousedown event is not recognised by the brush. When I click on the context area (brush), I don't have to drag and release the mouse to select an area. After clicking the selection of area goes to left and right automatically depending on the direction my mouse moves. Is that some kind of bug or due to some changes that I made in the code?

Comment: Which browser(s) are you using?

Comment: It would help to have a reproducible example, e.g. hosted at http://jsfiddle.com or http://bl.ocks.org